# Integration tests for asp.net core for UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, integration-testing

I have followed the instructions from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0#test-app-organization to create a test project.

Now I need to test that if the user is not authorized I get the correct page

In the Startup I have the following code

```
// use an error page for unhanded exceptions
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Home/{0}");
...
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
   ...
   endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
      name: "home_error",
      pattern: "Home/{statusCode}",
      defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "HttpStatusCodeHandler" },
      constraints: new { statusCode = new IntRouteConstraint() });
});
```

And I updated the TestAuthHandler to have something like

```
var result = AuthenticateResult.Fail("FAIL");
return Task.FromResult(result);
```

But the controller action from Home is not called. I do receive the status Unauthorized.

Can this be achieved in the integration tests?

PS: the access is done using Policy and Claims

Comment: Have you add a breakpoint in your controller and debug Test? on myside,I could get into the ErrorHandle method ,and the statuecode keeps 401, have you tried to read the content of the response?

Comment: Like I already said I am receiving the Unauthorized status but the code from HttpStatusCodeHandler returns a view with a specific message for each status code and I want to test that.

The code from HttpStatusCodeHandler is executed when I have a bad request so the issue seems to be with the TestAuthHandler

Comment: I have managed to debug further and indeed the Home/statuscode is called but Home has the attribute Authorized on it so I need to find a better way of failing

Comment: Try add [Allowanonymous] Attribute on your allowanonymous endpoint

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Ruikai Feng for point out that the code works for him I was able to identify the problem

The code about the authentication had to be changed to:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
  options.DefaultScheme = DefaultAuthenticationScheme;
  options.DefaultForbidScheme = DefaultAuthenticationScheme;
})
```

After adding the DefaultForbidScheme there was no need to fail the AuthenticationResult and the code was working as expected.